# Show dynamically changing image from url (IP-camera) with kivy

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy, ip-camera

So, I have an IP-camera and i know an url of image from IP-camera in jpg format. I want to add this image to Kivy application,but when I added url to AsyncImage's source it just show reload circle all the time,without showing image. Is it a way to show image with a time interval, e.g. every 500 milliseconds?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use Android's Handler :

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run(){
                 // do your work
         }}, 500); //time in 500 millisecond
```

**Edit:**
For python, use this :

```
def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start()
```

Comment: But is it possible to do this in Kivy (python)?